# Python Generating random even numbers using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

A contrived example to try and understand Python list comprehensions

I want to generate a list of 1000 random even numbers in the range of 1 to 100
This is what I have

```
import random
list = [random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(1,1000) if _ %2 ==0]
```

I am not able to figure out how to check the result of the randint() in the for loop.

I know this can possibly be done with `random.randrange(x,y,2)` or another mechanism. I want to understand if I can do it in the list comprehension way.

Comment: I recommend you to recheck the code because when I printed the `list`, it gave an output of random numbers which were both even and odd

Comment: A trick to assign a value to a variable in a comprehension list is to use `for var in [val]`, so your expression becomes `[x for _ in xrange(1000) for x in [random.randint(1,100)] if x % 2 ==0]` (note that the order of the for's matter). This assigns the only element in `[random.randint(1,100)]` to `x` for your specific use

Comment: @PhuNgo ooh, that's true. I recommend you write that in as an answer (though I'd drop the `xrange` -- Python3 has been out for over a decade now).

Comment: Why don't you create numbers from 1 to 50 and mlutiply by 2?

Comment: `[x + (x % 2) for _ in range(1000) for x in [random.randint(1, 100)]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

of course you can use a list comprehension, just not like this. What you *could* do instead is to write a function that produces a random *even* number, then do:

```
[your_func() for _ in range(1000)]
```

`your_func` in this case could be:

```
while True:
    n = random.randint(1, 100)
    if n%2 == 0:
        yield n
```

But of course this is hardly better than your noted possibility using `random.randrange(2, 101, 2)`.

```
[random.randrange(2, 101, 2) for _ in range(1000)]
```

Comment: Does this mean that I can't refer to the result of the operation in [OPERATION for x in RANGE] within the body of the for loop?

Comment: @PavanKMutt that is *not a for-loop*, that is a *list comprehension*. They are different. And yes, python does not let you assign inside a comprehension

Comment: @PavanKMutt ... if you need to inspect the result of the operation you can use an inner comprehension as well eg `[x for x in (random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(1,1000)) if x % 2 == 0]`

Comment: @donkopotamus and of course there's no guarantee that the result of that will be 1000 elements. In fact it will be strictly less.

Comment: range should be till length of list=1000

Comment: @AdamSmith of course ... I didn't notice he needed strictly 1000 of them!  (and **strictly** less?  Only `1 - 0.5**1000` percent of the time ...)

Answer (score 0):

Old post but:

```
from random import randint
even = sum(randint(1, 100) % 2 == 0 for _ in range(1, 1000))
print(even)
```

Comment: This code generates a random number (even or odd) with an average of about 500

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def my_generator():
    while True:
        yield random.randrange(0,10000,2)
a=my_generator()
print(next(a))
```

Every time you run this code,it generates an even number in range 0-10000(you can easily change start and stop in `rangerandom.randrange(start,stop,step)` here `step=2` to generate even numbers)